# "Was impressed by"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I am not so good at English, because it is not my native language.

> I have chosen Nelson Mandela, because he brought freedom into the world, and I was impressed by the way he did it.

Is "by" the right word to use here?

Comment: I mean help in the second sentence.

Comment: Yes it is. You can be impressed by him, by the way he did it, by his actions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, *by* is correct here. One of the times we use *by* is when talking about the way in which something was done. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/by_2) even calls out this usage as a definition of *by*.

You could also use *with*. Both prepositions are correct in this case, but *by* is [currently more popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impressed%20with,impressed%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,impressed%20with;,c0;.t1;,impressed%20by;,c0).

> I have chosen Nelson Mandela, because he brought freedom into the world, and I was impressed *with* the way he did it.